# Displaying dates values for current date in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, date, datetime

I am trying to filter out the values based on the date which should be within today's date. I am using the below query, however the query is not working as expected.

This is what I am using in SQL Server.

```
select values 
from table 
where date between DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0) 
           and GETDATE()
```

I am expecting the date to be filtered for values between '2015-03-18 00:00:00' AND '2015-03-18 23:59:59' if I am executing the query on 18th March 2015.

Please guide.

Comment: what you are expecting from "DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0) 
           and GETDATE()" ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's much better to use a `>=` and `<` than `BETWEEN`:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE
    date >= CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AS DATETIME)
    AND date < DATEADD(DAY, 1, CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AS DATETIME))
```

---

`CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AS DATETIME)` will get you the current date without the time part that is `2015-03-18 00:00:00`

`DATEADD(DAY, 1, CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AS DATETIME))` will get you the next day, again without the time part.

So in turn, your `WHERE` condition would be:

```
WHERE
    date >= '2015-03-18 00:00:00'
    AND date < '2015-03-19 00:00:00'
```

---

Alternatively, you can use this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE
    date >= DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), 0)        -- beginning of this day 
    AND date < DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, 0) -- beginning of next day
```

For more date calculations, refer to this [**article.**](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/lynnpettis/2009/03/25/some-common-date-routines/)

Answer (score 1):

> As You are Expecting value between '2015-03-18 00:00:00' AND
>   '2015-03-18 23:59:59. so, you can simply compare only date part.

you can Use Cast()/Convert():

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE
    cast(date as date) =cast(getdate() as date)
```

It included 2015-03-18 00:00:00' AND '2015-03-18 23:59:59'